# In highCharts so much space left for each category when using index with data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to HighCharts; In our project, we are using the below code where we are giving index value along with data (I won't be able to post the actual code)

```
      data.push([indx,getRandomInt(50)]);                       
      splitSeries[i].push({
          "name" : optionData.series[m].name,
          "data" : data
      });
```

But we are facing two problems

1. The categories are getting divided equally even though the first category has more number of bars.
2. There's so much space left at the bottom of each category.

   [image: chart after rendering]

How to resolve these issues, please help.

[Adding jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hzypqms/)

Comment: can you provide sample code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: done could you please check now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the distance between points by reducing `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` properties: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82f6joyq/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    }
}
```

However, Highcharts reserves space in a category for each series, so if you want to completely eliminate gaps, you need to use `breaks`. For example in this way:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series,
                breaks = [],
                hasValue,
                breakSize = 1 / series.length,
                i = 0,
                j,
                k = -1,
                tickPos,
                prevTickPos,
                xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
                categories = xAxis.categories;

            function hasData(el) {
                if (el === i) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            for (i; i < categories.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < series.length; j++) {
                    hasValue = series[j].xData.some(hasData);

                    if (!hasValue) {

                        breaks.push({
                            from: i + j * breakSize,
                            to: i + j * breakSize + breakSize
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            this.update({
                xAxis: {
                    breaks: breaks
                }
            }, true, true, false);

            for (k; k < categories.length; k++) {
                if (k !== -1) {
                    tickPos = xAxis.ticks[k].mark.getBBox();
                    xAxis.ticks[k].label.attr({
                        y: tickPos.y - (tickPos.y - prevTickPos.y) /
                            2 + xAxis.ticks[k].label.getBBox().height / 2
                    });
                }

                prevTickPos = tickPos || xAxis.ticks[k].mark.getBBox();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xcomk621/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Comment: hey thanks ...
But I have question why in my example the bars getting so squeezed ?
And in your example the bar with data:
            name: 'Q3',
            data: [[1, 3],], is being placed in index 0 whereas it should have been placed in index 1

Comment: Hi @YepMe, What do you exactly mean? could you prepare any simple visualization that shows your wanted result? The green point that you mention seems to be placed correctly - index 1, category `'2018-07'`.

Comment: Hi @YepMe, please check my answer and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly or not, but the above answer from @ppotaczek seems OK to me.

> Please refer this working example demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mukeshshamra1201/398Lw76y/).

Here I have added `gridLineWidth: 1` and `tickmarkPlacement: "between"` to demonstrate that tick is actually passing from middle.
 And as @ppotaczek said : You can change the distance between points by changing `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` properties.

Please let me know, if this works for you! :)

Since the link to fiddle.net must be accompanied by code I am including that here :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      inverted: true,
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['2018-06', '2018-07', '2018-08', '2018-09', '2018-10'],
      tickWidth: 1,
      tickmarkPlacement: "between",
      gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: -10,
      title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
    enabled :false,
      align: 'right',
      x: -70,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 20,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
      borderColor: '#CCC',
      borderWidth: 1,
      shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
          this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
          'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
      }
    },
   
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        groupPadding: 0.99,
        pointPadding: 0.99
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Q1',
      data: [
        [0, -5],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 7],
        [4, -2]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Q2',
      data: [
        [0, 5],
        [1, -3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, -7],
        [4, 2]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Q3',
      data: [
        [1, 3],
        [1, -4],
        [2, 7],
        [4, 2]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```